# Is it possible for a user to reference a previously created datatable by entering a string?

Tags: .net, string, datatable

I want a quick way to be able to see all of the data that is currently in a DataTable.
I want to be able to reference the name of the DataTable by entering string into a TextBox, have my program recognise that it's a DataTable that has data in it, and display that data in a DataGridView.
Maybe this isn't the best approach but it's better than creating a Select Case scenario for each datatable I've created.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably find a more robust way to do this.  However, if you really do wish to use this model, you can associate a string to a DataTable using `Dictionary<string, DataTable>`.  Look up the entered string (making sure to handle cases in which the string is not found) among the dictionary keys, and you'll have your DataTable.